# Spring session issue in Micro-service

Tags: java, session, microservices, spring-session, session-management

I am trying to handle session in microservice application using spring session and I am storing session in mysql database.

here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId></dependency>
```

This is where I am specifing database configuration and some spring session attributes. I am setting session time to 24 hours and I am specifying spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema to always so that Spring will create the required tables for us.

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: jdbc
    jdbc.initialize-schema: always
server:
 servlet:
     session:
         timeout: 86400
```

This is how I am creating session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("email", "abc@gmail.com");
```

Till here everything works fine and session is getting created for 24 hours in database table, but problem here is, sessions are getting cleared automatically before specified time.

I have searched a lot but still not able to fix this issue. Am I missing any configuration here or do I need to add anything extra to work this as expected ?